# bash - cascading case statement? (v. 3.2.51)

Tags: bash, case

I'm using bash version 3.2.51. My script needs a function to enter at different steps of the main function and continue doing the other steps after the chosen one.

I tried the following:

```
case $variable in
 1)
   function1
   ;&
 2)
   function2
   ;&
 *)
   function3
   ;;
esac
```

I used the ;& terminator so my script executes the statements afterwards aswell, without checking them. But after some research I found that due to me not having bash version 4 I get following syntax error:

```
./script.sh: line 223: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
./script.sh: line 223: `            ;&'
```

Line 223 would equal line 7 in the textbox above.

So my question is if there is another good option for bash 3 or if I have to execute the next function at the end of each function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`;&` was introduced in `bash` 4; you cannot use it in earlier versions of `bash`. You'll have to be explicit:

```
case $variable in
 1)
   function1
   function2
   function3
   ;;
 2)
   function2
   function3
   ;;
 *)
   function3
   ;;
esac
```

You could instead use a series of `if` statements (or more tersely, a series of `&&` lists):

```
(( variable <= 1 )) && function1
(( variable <= 2 )) && function2
(( variable <= 3 )) && function3
```

Comment: meh I guess the first option would be a lot of code cause I've got quite a lot of functions so far and there is no end in sight yet :P
buuuut the 2nd option seems quite good :-) ty
but one question: How would this option work if i have more than 9 functions?
What would you think of a counter or increasing $variable every step? Meaning i use read variable from stdin and add 1 in every case... would that work?^^

Comment: I switched from a more literal translation of the case statement to a list of arithmetic comparisons. This should work better for arbitrary values of `variable`, rather than assuming singe-digit values.

Comment: But another question, if I use `read variable` to get the variable, would I have to add `|| variable == ''` to the first option to start witch function1 if I don't enter anything into the read?

Comment: Immediately after the `read` command, give `$variable` a default value of 1 if the user didn't enter anything: `: ${variable:=1}`.

Comment: kk thx alot :-) unfortunately i cannot vote up your answer cause of insufficient rep^^

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
if [ $variable -eq 1 ]; then function1; fi
if [ $variable -gt 0 ] && [ $variable -le 2 ]; then function2; fi
function3
```

Comment: If you're going to do math, consider using a math context -- `if (( variable > 0 && variable <= 2 ))` is considerably more readable. If you're trying to stay compatible with POSIX sh, on the other hand, pay more attention to your quoting: `[ "$variable" -gt 0 ]`.

Comment: isn't it going to be a big pile of code if i have a lot of functions?